# external NSString from NSDictionary string item

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdictionary, external, global

I have a PList with strings and a dictionary. I am loading it in to an NSDictionary object, that much I've worked out fine. What I'm stuck with is getting a string entry from the NSdictionary object in to an external string, because by the time the external variable references the object (gotten with "ObjectByKey") from a separate class, the NSDictionary is no longer anywhere to be found. My question is, how do I get a string from an NSDictionary as a static string - not as a reference to an NSDictionary string entry? Below is my code:

loginGlobals.h

```
extern NSString *loginError;
```

LoginProcessorViewController.m

```
NSDictionary *responseData = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];

loginError = [responseData objectForKey:@"Error"];
```

and then the error comes up (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) when I do this in loginViewController.m:

```
loginErrorLabel.text = loginError;
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you use ARC on all of your projects. It prevents code like this from crashing, and apple strongly suggests you use it as well.

Comment: Thank you Richard, I had forgotten I disabled that for some reason.. re-enabling it and removing all references to my release and dealloc calls fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retain the `loginError` object

```
loginError = [[responseData objectForKey:@"Error"] retain];
```